# Error function().String undefined (type string has no field or method String)

Tags: go, struct, grpc

I tried to run a code based on gRPC service in Go, but failed to debug all the way to get it done. Here I add my part of my code below. plz feel free to post any code suggestions or comments.

```
    func (b *BookInfo) GetRate(ctx context.Context, xr *pb.RateRequest) (*pb.RateResponse, error) {
    // b.log.Info("Handle request for GetRate", "Article Name", xr.GetArticleName(), "Article Review", xr.GetArticleReview())
    log.Printf("Received: ", "Article Name", xr.GetArticleName(), "Article Review", xr.GetArticleReview())

    rt, err := b.rating.GetRatings(xr.GetArticleName().String(), xr.GetArticleReview().String())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &pb.RateResponse{Rating: rt}, nil

}
```

saved in bookInfo_server

```
func (x *RateRequest) GetArticleName() string {
    if x != nil {
        return x.ArticleName
    }
    return ""
}

func (x *RateRequest) GetArticleReview() string {
    if x != nil {
        return x.ArticleReview
    }
    return ""
}
```

for last part

```
type RateResponse struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Rating Ratings `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=rating,proto3,enum=Ratings" json:"rating,omitempty"`
}
```

saved in bookInfo.pb.go file

Error:

```
bookInfo_server/bookInfo_server.go:28:52: xr.GetArticleName().String undefined (type string has no field or method String)
bookInfo_server/bookInfo_server.go:28:84: xr.GetArticleReview().String undefined (type string has no field or method String)
bookInfo_server/bookInfo_server.go:33:26: cannot use rt (type string) as type bookInfo.Ratings in field value
```

Comment: Use `xr.GetArticleName()`, not `xr.GetArticleName().String()`. Last error depends on the type definitions of `Ratings`

Comment: Yes the above ans is right

Answer (score 1):

The type string has no method or field for the `xr.GetArticleName().string` in first & second errors,

Instead of that you can use `xr.GetArticleName()` in the code

The last error was for the type definition of the `Ratings`.